# Most Efficient Way to Ping for HTTP Code

Tags: php, http

I'm considering a website monitoring feature for a SaaS I run. It doesn't need to be very complex (i.e. no checks from multiple locations, no fancy reporting, and at most a 15-30 minute frequency).  Just something to send a quick email to the admin if the site responds with an unexpected HTTP code.

My initial thought was to run a crobjob every 15 minutes and let a PHP script check on each site.  Using [php-multi-curl](https://github.com/jmathai/php-multi-curl), I'm able to average about two sites per second max.  This could take awhile for 10,000 or 20,000 sites, so my question is, what's a better approach?  A daemon?  Multiple servers handling a central queue?

I'm looking for something that can handle pinging a large number of sites without being too resource intensive.  This isn't a dedicated monitoring service—just an added feature to an existing service.

**Edit:** It might help to know how services such as Pingdom and AreMySitesUp operate.

Comment: consider not using php. It's not intended for parallel operations.

Comment: Clearly, the goal is to find an alternative to the method I mentioned above.

Comment: maybe something that utilizes ping itself, rather than curl?

Comment: @riverc: ping just tells you if a particular IP is reachable. That has nothing to do with whether a website(s) at that IP are actually reachable

Comment: You will need to fork multiple processes or threads to get a http response for 10k - 20k sites back in a sensible time. Especially if you figure in waiting for timeouts on sites that may be down. As Marc B has suggested, php is probably not your best bet

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If having stuff on the crontab is fine enough you can write a shellscript for that. To figure out how the site is you can use:

```
curl -w %{http_code} -o /dev/null --silent (your target)
```

It will just return the http status code or 000 if domain unreachable (for whatever reason).

You then use another commandline tool to send the mail and is pretty fast.

(I'm unsure though how detailed you want your answer, for more details just leave a comment.)

Comment: Just looking for the right direction to go...it sounds like I'm going to be enlisting some help for this one. Would running curl via shellscript be faster than multi-curl via PHP?

Comment: I haven't tested it yet, but I would very much assume so (because there is just curl and no php involved, which is pretty slow). Curl can be started multiple times anyway and bash scripts tend to be fast (I haven't measured it though)

Comment: Ok, I talked to a sys programmer friend of mine and he agrees that we should try this first. Using `nice` we should be able to do this without making it too resource intensive. Thanks for the advice :)